# Как передать массив $_POST в функцию

Tags: php

Есть функция, в которой фильтруются данные из пост запроса. Как передать в эту функцию сам пост массив и корректно вызвать функцию?

```
function postData(){    
    $text = filterData($_POST['text'], 'string');
    $link = filterData($_POST['link'], 'link');
    $date = filterData($_POST['date'], 'date');
}
```

Comment:     filterData($_POST);

Я так понимаю функция filterData где-то у вас написана, без её кода невозможно понять, как передать в эту функцию сам пост массив и корректно её вызвать.

Comment: А в чем проблема просто и передать в функцию?

    function postData($_POST['text'], $_POST['link'], $_POST['date'])
    {
        # code
    }

или я ваш вопрос не понял...

Comment: @ua6xh, ну это понятно. А как вызвать? Вот так не работает: `$data = postData($_POST);`

Comment: @--A, так слишком громоздко выглядит, хотелось бы сразу массив, не расписывая его

Comment: @xenon зачем его передавать, если это супер-глобальный массив? Непонятно. Рекомендую к использованию функцию `filter_input`. А вообще, смотрите в сторону `route`.

Answer (score 2):

Вызвать данную функцию в том файле, к которому вы делаете POST запрос.

```
<form action='/controllers/forms.php'>
```

В данном примере в файле forms.php. Если же action пуст или отсутствует, значит он отправляет запрос к тому же файлу, на котором отрисовывается сама форма. Массив $_POST является  суперглобальным, поэтому как аргумент его передавать не нужно, можно просто использовать внутри функции и забить на неймспейсы.

Answer (score -1):

Файл

```
name="check['id файла']"
```

Обработчик

```
$array = $_POST['check'];
func($array);
```

Функция

```
function func($array){
for($array as $key){
echo $array[$key];}}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не содержит решения вопроса.